# FUSE filesystem to monitor any created/deleted file

Tags: python-2.7, fuse

I am working on a project which requires monitoring the filesystem for any changes. I came across [this](https://github.com/terencehonles/fusepy) bindings for FUSE. Any ideas how to actually implement the monitoring task ?

Basically I need to invoke a certain method whenever any new file is created.

Answer (score 1):

Inotify is for the monitoring task, and there is a python binding for this : [pyinotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify). Following is a simple example for monitoring creation of new files:

```
import pyinotify
wm = pyinotify.WatchManager()
notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(wm)
wm.add_watch('/tmp', pyinotify.IN_CREATE)
notifier.loop()
```

Accordint to [comment in fusepy](https://github.com/terencehonles/fusepy/issues/5), fusepy should work with inotify.

Comment: Thanks. pyinotify isn't able to monitor to FUSE filesystem for some reason. But still I think I can work something out for that. Thanks for introducing me to a pyinotify. Pretty cool stuff can be done using this. :)